# How to save "respose data" from JDBC Request to csv file

Tags: csv, jdbc, jmeter, httprequest, web-api-testing

I am using CSV data config as input file in that I have HTTP request parameters stored. After hitting HTTP Request I am using JDBC request to retrieve the result from the database for same http request.

How can I store the Response data getting from JDBC request into csv.
As I need to store in csv the input parameter and the response data .
Is there any way where I can store it?
Below is the JDBC request the result value I want to store in front of input data

[JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d0eR.png)

[JDBC Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmrRE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a single value as a result you can put something like `RESULT` into the "Variable Names" section

[image: JDBC JMeter Result]

After that you have 2 options:

1. Append these 2 Variables values to JMeter .jtl results file (recommended). To do this add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=TRANSACTION_ID,RESULT_1
   ```

   See [Sample Variables User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) section for more details
2. Write the files to a new CSV file. In that case you will need to add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the code like (assumes Groovy language):

   ```
   def csvFile = new File("file.csv")

   csvFile << vars.get("TRANSACTION_ID")
   csvFile << ","
   csvFile << vars.get("RESULT_1")
   csvFile << System.getProperty("line.separator")
   ```

Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn more about working with the JMeter's JDBC Test Elements results and result sets.

Comment: Hey @Dmitri, Thank you for the response. I tried the first option and I see transaction ID got populated correctly but RESULT_1 is coming out as NULL.. Can you please suggest why it is so?

Comment: Maybe database query returns NULL?

Comment: @dimitriT Actually I see the response in the response data field for the scenario. I wanted to attach an image to show you the response but I am not able attach here so I edited the question and there is JDBC RESPONSE link. Can you please take a look.. its in json format. the data is from database itself

Comment: Hey @Dmitri , Can you please see my above comment ? Please let me know about this.